# Prolog - split_string on every element in list

Tags: string, list, split, prolog

I am trying to cleanup some data in the form of a list by using `split_string` on every element on the list.

Let me give you an example of what I mean

Input:

```
[
 'p1\tp2\t100\tStorgatan', 
 'p1\tp3\t200\tLillgatan', 
 'p2\tp4\t100\tNygatan', 
 'p3\tp4\t50\tKungsgatan', 
 'p4\tp5\t150\tKungsgatan'
]
```

The result I expect after cleanup:

```
[
 [p1, p2, 100, Storgatan], 
 [p1, p3, 200, Lillgatan], 
 [p2, p4, 100, Nygatan], 
 [p3, p4, 50, Kungsgatan], 
 [p4, p5, 150, Kungsgatan]
]
```

I have tried to write a predicate that does this but for some reason my predicate won't return a result (output is just 'true'):

```
data_cleanup([], Res).   
data_cleanup([H|T], Res):-
    split_string(H, "\t", "", L),
    append([L], Res, NewRes),
    data_cleanup(T, NewRes).
```

I am quite new to Prolog so I am having a hard time figuring out what I've done wrong here. Help?

Thanks!

Comment: you didn't show how you call it. what's your sample query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
data_cleanup([], []).   
data_cleanup([H|T], [A|B]):-
    split_string(H, "\t", "", A),
    data_cleanup(T, B).
```

Now it does something:

```
?- data_cleanup(['p1\tp2\t100\tStorgatan', 'p1\tp3\t200\tLillgatan', 'p2\tp4\t100\tNygatan', 'p3\tp4\t50\tKungsgatan', 'p4\tp5\t150\tKungsgatan'], Result).
Result = [["p1", "p2", "100", "Storgatan"], ["p1", "p3", "200", "Lillgatan"], ["p2", "p4", "100", "Nygatan"], ["p3", "p4", "50", "Kungsgatan"], ["p4", "p5", "150", "Kungsgatan"]].
```

Exercise: define this predicate using `maplist`.

EDIT: or if you are anyway using SWI-Prolog, and if you prefer atoms and not strigs, you could use `atomic_list_concat/3`:

```
split_atom(Delimiter, Atom, List) :- atomic_list_concat(List, Delimiter, Atom).
```

and then

```
?- maplist(split_atom('\t'), ['p1\tp2\t100\tStorgatan', 'p1\tp3\t200\tLillgatan', 'p2\tp4\t100\tNygatan', 'p3\tp4\t50\tKungsgatan', 'p4\tp5\t150\tKungsgatan'], L).
L = [[p1, p2, '100', 'Storgatan'], [p1, p3, '200', 'Lillgatan'], [p2, p4, '100', 'Nygatan'], [p3, p4, '50', 'Kungsgatan'], [p4, p5, '150', 'Kungsgatan']].
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question... why is it not possible to use `split_string` with `maplist`?

Comment: @Schytheron of course it is possible to use `split_string` with `maplist`, but you need an adaptor just like with `atomic_list_concat`. So, you'd need to define a predicate defined in terms of `split_string/4` where the last two arguments are the string and the list after splitting. For example: `split_on(Delimiter, Str, List) :- split_string(Str, Delimiter, "", List).` and then query `?- maplist(split_on("\t"), ["a\tb", "c\td"], Lists).`