# Prolog - Keep track of multiple sum counters

Tags: list, prolog, sum, counter, accumulate

So I have a list that looks like this:

```
[ 
  ["p1", "p2", "100", "Storgatan"], 
  ["p1", "p3", "200", "Lillgatan"], 
  ["p2", "p4", "100", "Nygatan"], 
  ["p3", "p4", "50", "Kungsgatan"], 
  ["p4", "p5", "150", "Kungsgatan"]
]
```

The elements in each nested list represent (in order):
1st element = Start Point
2nd element = End Point
3rd element = Distance
4th element = Street Name.

I have to now write a predicate which figures out which street is the shortest and which street is the longest, along with their respective (summed up) distances.

For example the final output should look something like this:

```
Longest street: Kungsgatan, 200
Shortest street: Storgatan, 100
```

I don't really understand why the start and end points are relevant information here. My current idea is to collect all the unique street names, put them in a separate list along with a counter for each street that starts at zero and then use that list to accumulate all of the distances for each separate street.

Something like:

```
create_sum_list([
   ["p1", "p2", "100", "Storgatan"], 
   ["p1", "p3", "200", "Lillgatan"], 
   ["p2", "p4", "100", "Nygatan"], 
   ["p3", "p4", "50", "Kungsgatan"], 
   ["p4", "p5", "150", "Kungsgatan"]
], SL).

SL= [[Storgatan, 0], [Lillgatan, 0],
     [Nygatan, 0], [Kungsgatan ,0]]

accumulate(SL, List).

List=[[Storgatan, 100], [Lillgatan, 200], 
      [Nygatan, 100], [Kungsgatan ,200]]
```

This is probably a stupid idea and there is probably a way better way to solve this. I have thought of many different ideas where I either reach a dead end or they are way too complex for such a "simple" task.

I can achieve this easily through "normal" imperative programming but I am new to logical programming and Prolog. I have no idea how to achieve this.

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: @GuyCoder Does it make a big difference? I genuinely don't know. I could convert them to atoms I guess?

Comment: @GuyCoder That's not a typo. Kungsgatan's length IS 200. You see how Kungsgatan appears twice in my list with 50 and 150 (150+50=200)? I am summing up the streets TOTAL length.

Comment: It's homework but I made up the structure of the data/list. The task before this one (which I have done) was to read a file and split up the contents into an "appropriate data structure". The file had each nested list as a separate line. For example first came `p1\tp2\t100\tStorgatan` followed by `p1\tp3\t200\tLillgatan` on the next line.There is a related post I created here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159054/prolog-split-string-on-every-element-in-list

Comment: @GuyCoder Here is the file contents: https://pastebin.com/V70Ubs4M and here is the code I used to read the file and output the above list structure: https://pastebin.com/3n1Htjgs

Comment: @GuyCoder Nope, there is no follow-up task. This is the last task in my homework.

Comment: @GuyCoder No, no. I don't expect you to do anything but since you mentioned that you will work on "adding the lenghts together" I thought that I might give you a heads up before starting in cased you missed it. I appreciate all the help you've given me so far. Don't take it the wrong way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a list and you want to group by street name and sum the lengths, you must decide how you do the grouping. One way is to use library(pairs):

```
streets_lengths(S, L) :-
    maplist(street_name_and_length, S, NL),
    keysort(NL, NL_sorted),
    group_pairs_by_key(NL_sorted, G),
    maplist(total_lengths, G, GT),
    transpose_pairs(GT, By_length), % sorts!
    group_pairs_by_key(By_length, L).

street_name_and_length([_, _, N, L], L_atom-N_number) :-
    number_string(N_number, N),
    atom_string(L_atom, L).

total_lengths(S-Ls, S-T) :-
    sum_list(Ls, T).
```

You can use it like this:

```
?- streets_lengths([
   ["p1", "p2", "100", "Storgatan"],
   ["p1", "p3", "200", "Lillgatan"],
   ["p2", "p4", "100", "Nygatan"],
   ["p3", "p4", "50", "Kungsgatan"],
   ["p4", "p5", "150", "Kungsgatan"]
], SL).
SL = [100-['Storgatan', 'Nygatan'], 200-['Lillgatan', 'Kungsgatan']].
```

Since there can be many streets with the same length, the results are returned grouped by length. You can get the "shortest" and "longest" by getting the first and last element of the list, like this:

```
L = [First|_], last(L, Last)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you just explain to me what the `-` in the predicate "arguments" means (for example, `L_atom-N_number` or `S-T` etc.)? Also, is there a "recommended" data structure I can use for my list to make the solution simpler or does it not matter?

Comment: Nvm, I think the `-` operator creates a pair in Prolog. Feel so dumb now haha.

Comment: I noticed a big flaw in your code. Your code does not work if 2 equal street names are not consecutive in the list. For example, if I took the last nested list in my list and moved it to the front of the list. Probably because `group_pairs_by_key` only groups values with equivalent CONSECUTIVE keys :(

Comment: Yes, you must sort by key first! It says it in the documentation as well -- fixed it. There are other things I didn't take care of (it is your problem after all), the points. I don't know what they are supposed to mean, but I guess they are also important for connecting parts of streets together?

Comment: My solution now sorts before grouping. But you altogether need to think more carefully what you are doing. There are endless different ways to solve it. This is only one approach (and I am not convinced it is best for your purpose).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed I could use `keysort` like 5 mins after I made my comment. Sometimes I don't think before I talk (or write) haha. Thanks for the answer though. It's been real helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework I won't give you the entire answer but the key part of the code.

As I noted in the comments, the format of the structure matters, e.g. list, terms, atoms, strings, etc.

```
test(Street_lengths,Shortest) :-
    List =
        [
         street(p1, p2, 100, 'Storgatan'),
         street(p1, p3, 200, 'Lillgatan'),
         street(p2, p4, 100, 'Nygatan'),
         street(p3, p4, 50,  'Kungsgatan'),
         street(p4, p5, 150, 'Kungsgatan')
        ],
    street_lengths(List,Street_lengths),
    lengths1(Street_lengths,Lengths),
    min_list(Lengths,Min),
    convlist(value_shortest2(Min),Street_lengths,Shortest).

street_lengths([H|T],Street_lengths) :-
    merge_streets(H,T,Street_lengths).

% 2 or more items in list
merge_streets(street(_,_,Length0,Name),[street(_,_,Length1,Name),street(_,_,Length2,Name2)|Streets0],[street(Length,Name)|Streets]) :-
    Length is Length0 + Length1,
    merge_streets(street(_,_,Length2,Name2),Streets0,Streets).
merge_streets(street(_,_,Length0,Name0),[street(_,_,Length1,Name1)|Streets0],[street(Length0,Name0)|Streets]) :-
    Name0 \= Name1,
    merge_streets(street(_,_,Length1,Name1),Streets0,Streets).

% 1 item in list
merge_streets(street(_,_,Length0,Name),[street(_,_,Length1,Name)],[street(Length,Name)]) :-
    Length is Length0 + Length1.
merge_streets(street(_,_,Length0,Name0),[street(_,_,Length1,Name1)],[street(Length0,Name0)|Streets]) :-
    Name0 \= Name1,
    merge_streets(street(_,_,Length1,Name1),[],Streets).

% no item in list
merge_streets(street(_,_,Length,Name),[],[street(Length,Name)]).

lengths1(List,Lengths) :-
    maplist(value_length1,List,Lengths).

value_length1(street(Length,_),Length).

value_shortest2(Min,street(Min,Name),street(Min,Name)).
```

Example run:

```
?- test(Street_lengths,Shortest).
Street_lengths = [street(100, 'Storgatan'), street(200, 'Lillgatan'), street(100, 'Nygatan'), street(200, 'Kungsgatan')],
Shortest = [street(100, 'Storgatan'), street(100, 'Nygatan')] ;
false.
```

I left the longest for you to do, but should be a cake walk.

To display the information as you noted in the question I would use [format/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2).

So now you either have to change how you get the data read into the format for this code, or change this code to work with how you structured the data. IMHO I would change the data to work with this structure.

If want to know how efficient your code is you can use [time/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=time/1)

```
?- time(test(Street_lengths,Shortest)).
% 44 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
Street_lengths = [street(100, 'Storgatan'), street(200, 'Lillgatan'), street(100, 'Nygatan'), street(200, 'Kungsgatan')],
Shortest = [street(100, 'Storgatan'), street(100, 'Nygatan')] ;
% 17 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
false.
```

Comment: Also take into account that "Kungsgatan" is not the shortest street. "Storgatan"/"Nygatan" is.